# Session name not showing

Tags: php, html, sql

Am trying to show the value of the $login_session in my welcome page but it doesn't show.
Any help on that

Welcome.html:

```
<?php
   include("session.php");
?>
<html>
      <h1>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1> 
</html>
```

Session.php

```
:
<?php  
  include ("db_connection.php");    session_start();
    $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
          $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select First_name from User where Email = '$user_check' ");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $login_session = $row['First_name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome.html ? try executing it as .php or You can't execute php in html file, unless you instruct Apache to treat .html files as PHP

to do this ,
Create a .htaccess file at the root of your website and add this line:

```
[Apache2 @ Ubuntu/Debian: use this directive]

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

If your are running PHP as CGI (probably not the case), you should write instead:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Also try with localhost / server !

Answer (score 1):

Bro, change the file extension in PHP and run it through any server or localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Is your webserver enabled to execute php in html files?

If the Browser call on Welcome.html returns the plain php code this is the reason why. Try renaming the welcome.html file into welcome.php update the call in your browser.